# How can I create a group call?

Tags: sinch

Our team is looking to use Sinch in an ongoing project, however we can't find anything on group VoIP. Is this currently supported or planned?

Comment: You might do better to contact the sinch team directly. SO is not really suited for these kinds of questions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Jake, please get in touch directly with us at dev@sinch.com 
As of today, group calling is not supported with the Sinch SDK